# Strip the output of the ping command?

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, macintosh, ping

I would like to as if it is possible to strip the result of the 'ping' command form the last three lines which are always:

```
--- domain.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.837/4.501/4.839/0.469 ms
```

Would it be possible to make ping to NOT show this lines?

I have tried with the following:

```
ping -c2 domain.com | xargs grep -v "statistics \|transmitted\|round-trip"
```

and also:

```
ping -c2 domain.com | grep -v "statistics \|transmitted\|round-trip"
```

But it does not seem to be working. This is tested on a Mac only. It is not tested on Linux.

So, i was wondering if it will be possible to make this work somehow? May be with awk or something?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the newline aswell?

Comment: @Panki the new line is not an issue. The last three lines are my concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ping -c2 domain.com | head -n-3
```

To get rid of the leading newline aswell:

```
ping -c2 domain.com | head -n-4
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly :) and it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
ping -c 2 domain.com | grep -E "PING|icmp_seq"
```

Or if You don't want first line

```
ping -c 2 domain.com | grep -E "icmp_seq"
```

Or If You really want to delete lines

```
ping -c 2 domain.com | sed '/statistics\|packets\|rtt\|^$/d'
```

^$ - is to delete empty lines

Comment: Thanks. This worked fine as well.